# Multiselect with JQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a listener that gets triggered on javascript keyup event. The listener makes an ajex call and get the result from server based on the search term. I need to select multiple values from the returned result. Below is my JQuery success function:

```
function searchResults() {
let $value = jQuery(this)
let val = $value.val();
var $id = "#email";
let baseUrl = "baseurl"
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "url",
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('CSRF_NONCE', 'Fetch');
    },
    success: function(res, status, responseHeader) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: baseUrl + "url",
            type: 'GET',
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('CSRF_NONCE', responseHeader.getResponseHeader("CSRF_NONCE"));
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var urlToHIt = baseUrl + "url"
                var parsedPayload = JSON.parse(data.payload);
                jQuery($id).autocomplete({
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: function(request, response) {
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            url: urlToHIt,
                            success: function(data) {
                                data = parsedPayload;
                                response(jQuery.map(data, function(item) {
                                    return {
                                        label: item.label,
                                        value: item.value
                                    }
                                }));
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    focus: function() {
                        return false;
                    },
                    select: function(event, ui) {
                        var terms = split(this.value);
                        terms.pop();
                        terms.push(ui.item.value);
                        terms.push("");
                        this.value = terms.join(", ");
                        return false;
                    },
                    close: function() {
                        jQuery('.ui-autocomplete').show()
                    },
                    });
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log("Failed", data)
                }
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("Failed")
        }
});
}

function split(val) {
    //return val.split(/,\s*/);
    return val.split(/,\s*/);
}

function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
}
```

The code works until I select one value. After selecting one value when I type again (please note, when I type again, the code will make the ajex call and `availableTags[]` may have new set of values), it stops showing me suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked up this example to show how. It's a little bit of a hack, but the user experience isn't affected. The specific answer to your question is

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
//..... ,
close: function() {
    $('.ui-autocomplete').show()
  }
})
```

and then create a separate control for closing the options list

```
$('button[data-role=ui-close]').click(function() {
  $('.ui-autocomplete').hide()
  $(this).hide()
})
```

```js
let availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell",
  "Java",
  "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby",
  "Scala",
  "Scheme"
];
$("#tags").autocomplete({
  open: function() {
    $('button[data-role=ui-close]').css('display', 'inline-block')
  },
  source: availableTags,
  select: function(event, ui) {
    let a = $('#multi').val().split(",");
    a.push(ui.item.value)
    $('#multi').val(a.filter(x => x).join(", "));
    return false;
  },
  close: function() {
    $('.ui-autocomplete').show()
  }

});

$('button[data-role=ui-close]').click(function() {
  $('.ui-autocomplete').hide()
  $(this).hide()
})
```

```css
button[data-role='ui-close'] {
  display: none;
}

.res {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags"><button data-role='ui-close' hidden>done</button>
  <div class='res'><textarea id="multi" cols="50" rows="2"></textarea></div>
</div>
```

---

**Dynamic Data**

[Per the docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), pull data from remote sources using the URL in the source attribute.

This will query your website with a GET request that has a `term` parameter. `source: "https://www.your-website.com"`  Make sure your remote script outputs the data as a stringified JSON array

```
jQuery("#email").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: "https://www.your-website.com",
    // ....
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reason why you added a text area to show the selected items?

Comment: Thanks and no other way then adding a button to close the list?

Comment: Yes, I showed how. It's a simple hide function: `$('.ui-autocomplete').hide()` when you want to trigger that is up to you. I provided a button as a UI element but it just calls that function

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as the solution, cheers!

Comment: I tried to place the selected elements in the same text box, but it append it to the typed characters. Also, if I change the characters, the suggestions doesn't appear. I had to clean the textbox to make them appear again.

Comment: Don't append the the search box because that will cause autocomplete to search for them. Rather, keep track of them (like I did in the text area). Keep the autocomplete input to have user input only.

Comment: Yeah, did like that only. Here:  `$("#tags").autocomplete({
  open: function() {
    $('button[data-role=ui-close]').css('display', 'inline-block')
  },
  source: availableTags,
  select: function(event, ui) {
    let a = $('#tags').val().split(",");
    a.push(ui.item.value)
    $('#tags').val(a.filter(x => x).join(", "));
    return false;
  },
  close: function() {
    $('.ui-autocomplete').show()
  }
});`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234046/discussion-between-pkj-and-kinglish).

Comment: I implemented your suggestions but it still doesn't show suggestions the second time. I have updated the code in my original post. Although, the suggestion list remains open, it doesn't refresh the list based on the new characters.

Comment: It doesn't show the ajax data the second time?

Comment: Nope, the list remains same. For example, if I type `test` first time, it will load the list based on test. The list now remains open. Now the second time If I type `book`, the list still remains the same.

Comment: Do you notice with the web inspector if it's sending an ajax request and that new data is being returned?

Comment: I did check and the next time list comes empty. Looks like it is not sending ajax request the second time. Also, upload an image here: https://ibb.co/ss5B3nR

Comment: The searchterm variable (`let validationResponse = $tb.val();`) was defined at the top and hence the search term was not getting refreshed. That was causing the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome. Happy for you! Cheers

Comment: Thanks. Quick questions - 1.) Is there a way to show the list only when user types instead of keep it always open? Having a button to close it looks a little less user friendly. 

2.) Is there a way to disable free text selection and let users select from the list only? Currently, it allows free text add as well.

Comment: 1. so, maybe a setTimeout from the last keyDown to make it go away if they stop typing for 5 seconds? Problem is that might cause multiple ajax requests... and 2. I don't understand this one, in the sample I can't select anything that isn't in the autocomplete suggestions area

Comment: Regarding# 2 - For some reason it wasn't working for me. I have fixed it. 
Regarding# 1 - It there a way to hide the list if a user clicks anywhere outside the search bar?

once again, thanks so much!